# Group Manager permissions not working when adding via game command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I wanted my Moderators and above to be able to /feed, and so I did the command:

"/mangaddp Moderator essentials.feed"

This then said that the permission had been given to the assigned group (and above due to inheritance).

Next I did "/manload" to make sure the groups were loaded properly, but alas, it says that I do not access to that command when I put myself in the Moderator group.

Comment: If you don't mind, please provide your permissions yml file. There may be a wildcarded denial of permission that is manifesting here, or some similar problem that will only be determinable with more detail on your configuration.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1db8ed0c04cab457b7d1

Comment: It looks like your /mangaddp command isn't adding essentials.feed into your permissions. Does the command output anything when you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you permissions by chance setup something like this?

```
Moderator:
    permissions:
    - -'*'
```

Cause if so, that wildcard is what is prohibiting the group from using the command.

I've had this sort of issue before, to where I would do that, thinking I can then add permissions that I want them to be able to use after, and it didn't work. If that is the case for you here, what I recommend is do the following:

```
Moderator:
    permissions:
    - -(command you want to deny here)
    - -(command you want to deny here)
    - (from here down, commands you don't want to deny)
```

If I confuse you, please let me know, and I will try to explain it a little better.

Here is something else thay may help you as well.

[Group Manager Permissions Info](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager)

[Essentials Permissions Nodes (Just in case)](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Command_Reference/Perm)